# How do you emulate react native on IOS

Tags: macos, react-native

In terminal when I run the following line I get an error message. Can someone please explain my error to me and tell me how I can finally emulate my react native app on ios?

`npm run ios`

> pm ERR! path /Users/(me)/package.json
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -2
>   npm ERR! syscall open
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/(me)/package.json'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/(me)/.npm/_logs/2018-12-23T07_08_01_594Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you run the command inside your project directory ?

Comment: Is this an `expo` or a `react-native init` app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean build  and then Use this command for run on ios

=> react-native run-ios

Comment: to use "react-native run-ios" you must install "react-native-cli" globally first, create project using "react-native init ProjectName" and run the command "react-native run-ios" under project directory..  Command to install: npm install -g react-native-cli

Comment: if you are using expo then use this command

"expo start"

check here
"https://itnext.io/set-up-react-native-with-expo-1e63a82d01ac"